# Import data from Raspberry Pi to PC using Ethernet

Tags: user-interface, raspberry-pi

I am using Raspberry Pi model B, in which I am running a program created with python, my program has to write some data into some Excel files. Now I want to import those files using my PC via ehernet. My pc is running windows. It would be more useful to create a gui which can help users to easily import those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block). Just create a shared folder in Windows and bind it in the `/etc/fstab` on RPi.

Another approach would be to use `SSH` i.e. [scp](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php).